# how to populate select clause of dataframe dynamically? giving AnalysisException

Tags: java, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am Using spark-sql 2.4.1 and java 8.

```
 val country_df = Seq(
    ("us",2001),
    ("fr",2002),
    ("jp",2002),
    ("in",2001),
    ("fr",2003),
    ("jp",2002),
    ("in",2003)
    ).toDF("country","data_yr")

> val col_df = country_df.select("country").where($"data_yr" === 2001)

    val data_df = Seq(
    ("us_state_1","fr_state_1" ,"in_state_1","jp_state_1"),
    ("us_state_2","fr_state_2" ,"in_state_2","jp_state_1"),
    ("us_state_3","fr_state_3" ,"in_state_3","jp_state_1")
    ).toDF("us","fr","in","jp")

> data_df.select("us","in").show()
```

how to populate this select clause (of data_df) dynamically , from the  country_df for given year ?

i.e. From first dataframe , i will get values of column , those are
 the columns i need to select from second datafame. How can this be
 done ?

> Tried this :

```
List<String> aa = col_df.select(functions.lower(col("data_item_code"))).map(row -> row.mkString(" ",", "," "), Encoders.STRING()).collectAsList();
 data_df.select(aa.stream().map(s -> new Column(s)).toArray(Column[]::new));
```

**Error :**

```
.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '` un `' given input columns: [abc,.....all columns ...]
```

So what is wrong here , and how to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with the below code.

Select the column name from the first dataset.

```
List<String> columns = country_df.select("country").where($"data_yr" === 2001).as(Encoders.STRING()).collectAsList();
```

Use the column names in selectexpr in second dataset.

```
public static Seq<String> convertListToSeq(List<String> inputList) {
        return JavaConverters.asScalaIteratorConverter(inputList.iterator()).asScala().toSeq();
}


//using selectExpr
data_df.selectExpr(convertListToSeq(columns)).show(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
scala> val colname = col_df.rdd.collect.toList.map(x => x(0).toString).toSeq

scala> data_df.select(colname.head, colname.tail: _*).show()
+----------+----------+
|        us|        in|
+----------+----------+
|us_state_1|in_state_1|
|us_state_2|in_state_2|
|us_state_3|in_state_3|
+----------+----------+
```

Comment: I am not seeing any column for sum  all are in String and Year. Could you please be specific about the case.

Answer (score 1):

Using pivot you can get the values as column names directly like this:

```
val selectCols = col_df.groupBy().pivot($"country").agg(lit(null)).columns
data_df.select(selectCols.head, selectCols.tail: _*)
```

Comment: `groupBy() ` to group by all the columns and `agg(lit(null)) ` just to get back a DataFrame after pivot, `lit(null)` as we don't need any data here except column names.